# Steps Requird in converting a web application to iPad

Tags: web-applications, ipad

What steps are required to convert an existing web application to iPad.
Any dev kit/SDK etc.

Comment: Do you want to re-develop your application to run directly on the ipad, or do you want to know what changes to make to a Web App to run correctly in Safari?

Comment: I think if my web app is running on Mac Safari then it will run on ipad, right? 
I want my web application to fully support the iPad capabilites, SO ipad user can enjoy my web app in iPad way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to start with:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html

**Update:**

Oh and one obvious controversial word: Flash

Answer (score 0):

Mostly web apps just work on an iPad browser, but generally you'll want to build a dedicated experience because mouse-optimized controls and navigation just don't work well when your fat-fingered users try to hit a tiny area on the screen (let's say a tree expander)

Also keep in mind these issues:

1) No Flash (no flash ads, no flash video, but also no annoying flash intros etc.)

2) Lousy iFrame support (so be prepared for facebook connect and everything else that relies on an iframe to break)

3) Caching oddnesses.

4) Watch out for the "same to home page" functionality. It's a very different web app within that web view than within the regular web browser.